# ! Missing \endcsname inserted on ClassicThesis

Tags: texlive, texstudio, classicthesis

I started using TexStudio today (with TexLive) on my Windows machine.
I uploaded a project on which I was previously working (on Overleaf). It uses the ClassicThesis package.

I tried to add the greek language writing `\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}` in the `ClassicThesis.tex` and it resulted in a `Option clash for babel` error.

So I deleted the babel line I added. From that moment, it does not compile the pdf anymore, saying

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                  \global 
l.3 ...1\EnsureStandardFontEncoding {ii}}{\mph@nr}
```

I checked the  `.aux` file previously generated (which I had saved on github), and other the same line is different. It is `\mph@setcol{ii:i}{\mph@nr}` , while on the new `.aux` file it is `\mph@setcol{ii:\global \let \T1\EnsureStandardFontEncoding \T1\EnsureStandardFontEncoding {ii}}{\mph@nr}`.

EDIT: in the `classicthesis_config.tex` file there is this code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{greek,american}{babel}   % change this to your language(s)
    \usepackage{babel}
```

I added the option greek now, and removed the `\usepackage{babel}` that I had mistakenly added.

The problem persists. Even if I delete the `.aux` file, it rewrites it in the same way.

EDIT nr2: here there is a minimal example. Three files are involved.

Main `.tex` document:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % fix some latex issues see: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf
\documentclass[ oneside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
               greek,american, %
                ]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\corrections[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} 

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\include{DirtyTitlepage}

\end{document}
```

And here the code from the config document:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
    \usepackage{inputenc}

\newcommand{\myTitle}{MyTitle\xspace}
\PassOptionsToPackage{greek,american}{babel} 
    \usepackage{babel}    

\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
    backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
    language=auto,%
    style=numeric-comp,%
    sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
    maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
    %backref=true,%
    natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}

\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
    \usepackage{fontenc}     
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package          
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym} 
    \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
    \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\acsfont{#1}}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
    {%
       \addto\extrasamerican{%
            \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
            \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
            \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
            \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
            \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
            \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
            \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%     
                }%
       \addto\extrasngerman{% 
            \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
            \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Unterabsatz}%
            \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
            \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
            \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
            \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
            \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%        
            \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
                }%  
            \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%             
    }{\relax}
\makeatother

\usepackage{classicthesis}
```

Finally, the DirtyTitlePage code:

```
%*******************************************************
% Little Dirty Titlepage
%*******************************************************
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\pdfbookmark[1]{Titel}{title}
%*******************************************************
\begin{center}
    \spacedlowsmallcaps{\myTitle} \\ \medskip                        

    \begingroup
        \color{Blue}\spacedallcaps{\myTitle}
    \endgroup
\end{center}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: you probably need to give more clues. Start by deleting the `.aux` file (that is always safe as latex re-writes it every time) you can only get the `Option clash for babel ` if you load babel twice, but as you show no code, can not really help with that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I modified the post adding some code. Anyways, the problem is that I cannot compile anymore, even if I resolved the `option clash for babel` problem.

Comment: we can't run your code as it `\include` files we don't have but it does not appear to use classicthesis at all? is there a `\usepackage{classicthesis}` missing?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle for some reason it didn't paste the whole code. I just fixed it. I know there are not all the files included, but I didn't change anything in there. They were working before.

Comment: yes but if you post files we can't use we can not debug for you, you should make a small example that shows the problem and then we can run it and see if we can reproduce the problem

Comment: You're loading Babel for Greek and US English, but you're adding to settings for US English and German. There's also a lot of stuff which doesn't make much sense in your configuration file e.g. `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<pkg>}\usepackage{<pkg>}` seems needlessly convoluted. Are you sure about that ASCII encoding? If you started on Overleaf, but even if you didn't, that would be very surprising. Do you know why you are loading each package with the options you've set? Because some of them even have notes suggesting they're purposeless.

Comment: @cfr I am not Latex expert, so I just took the ClassicThesis template and used it, modifying just what I really need to. I don't know about the packages loaded. I modified now the options of the `\documentclass` with greek instead of german, but the problem persists. I don't know what you mean about the ASCII encoding...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should I add to the post all the other documents included?

Comment: @ValeriaBoano no! do not add more, just make a more sensible example that makes it easy for peaople to test. Do you _need_ `\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}` to show the error, if not remove it.  Remove all the text and `\input` commands that you can remove while showing the error, then remove every `\usepackage` not used in the example, then post a small self contained document that shows the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, thanks for your help and patience. I will edit the post now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just edited the post.

Comment: thanks, i'll look

Answer (score 1):

beware loading hundreds of packages that you can not possibly need (some like `fixltx2e` do nothing at all)

Something is defining `\@roman` in a way that it no longer expands to a roman numeral, this could break lots of things, but here it breaks `mparhack`.

You can restore `\@roman` by using

```
\let\tmp\@roman
\input{classicthesis-config}
\let\@roman\tmp
```

Comment: `> \@roman=macro:
#1->\expandafter \EnsureStandardFontEncoding \expandafter {\romannumeral #1}.
<recently read> \@roman 
                        
l.254 \expandafter\show\csname @roman\endcsname
                                               
? i
insert>\show\EnsureStandardFontEncoding
> \EnsureStandardFontEncoding=macro:
->\LGR-cmd \EnsureStandardFontEncoding \LGR\EnsureStandardFontEncoding .` Can be reproduced with standard `report`, `babel` and `mparhack`. The rest is unnecessary.

Comment: @cfr ah Greek babel then I guess, I'll look later thanks, I didn't have the heart to dig further earlier mpsrhsck is an innocent bistander it is supposed to be able to trust writing `\thepage` to a file, but that definition means that will fail

Comment: Example below. I think it would make sense to use either `greek.no-LGR-fixes` or `greek.local-LGR-fixes`, but I think whether the second is sufficient depends on stuff I don't know about the document. Do you know what the changes are meant to fix?

Comment: @cfr the changes are designed to locally switch out of LGR so roman 4 typesets as  latin i v not iota nu, because (apparently) the romans used latin not greek

Comment: I suppose that *might* be true.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal document reproducing the issue is

```
\documentclass[%
  greek,%
  american,%
]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mparhack}

\begin{document}
  
\pagenumbering{roman}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  a
\end{center}  

\end{document}
```

This fails with

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.6 ...T1\EnsureStandardFontEncoding {i}}{\mph@nr}
                                                  
? x
```

As David said, the problem is that something redefines `\@roman` in a way which plays havoc with `mparhack`. That something is `greek.ldf` which contains the language definitions for Greek when `babel` is used with (pdf)TeX.

I suggest using one of `babel-greek`'s recommended methods for changing this behaviour rather than simply overriding the changes it makes. There are two options: switch off the changes the package makes completely or switch them off locally when Greek is not active.

If your document uses Greek as the main language, you probably want to switch them off globally but if, as your preamble suggests, English is the main language, it should be sufficient to switch them off locally. In particular, if English is the main language used for the front and back matter, disabling the change locally in this way should be enough.

```
\documentclass[% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701031/
  greek,%
  american,%
]{report}
\usepackage[greek.local-LGR-fixes,american]{babel}
\usepackage{mparhack}

\begin{document}
  
\pagenumbering{roman}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  a
\end{center}  

\end{document}
```

If that's not sufficient, replace `greek.local-LGR-fixes` with `greek.no-LGR-fixes`.

Note that 99% of the time answering this consisted in producing a minimal example to reproduce the error, which is something you could and should do for yourself next time.

Comment: Reported at https://codeberg.org/milde/greek-tex/issues/1#issuecomment-1330965

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is using the language option a reasonable answer? (Should I delete this?)

Comment: no don't delete (I referenced it in the bug report) Using the language option is a reasonable answer and what the OP should do (ie accept this not mine) but really packages should not have a `[do-not-break-latex]` option so it would be better if the package didn't break latex in the first place.  But that might be tricky, the reason the Greek is `LGR` not `Txx` is that supporting Greek and following the rules for supported `T.` encodings proved impossible, so by design LGR has to "break" some things. In the bug report I suggested some code so at this example works without the option.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your help! Now it works. I am gradually learning how to use Latex and so it was not easy to find where the error was. I tried deleting more from my code but it caused other errors, and so I was unsure. Thank you again

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your time and your help.

Comment: @ValeriaBoano There is a kind of mechanical process for minimising, but it is easy to make a mistake even when you've done it before. Generally speaking, try reproducing with one of the core classes and use that if you can, because it removes a layer of complexity. Once I took the KOMA stuff out, it was easier.